# Specific user's SSH-RSA with root access (via AWS EC2)

Tags: ssh, login, sshd, amazon-ec2, aws

Is it possible to set up a specific SSH-RSA key (via another user i.e. "ec2-user") to have ability to sudo into root.

I.e.

1. You login with key to "Bob" (ec2-user).  Currently user "Bob" can sudo into root.
2. "Bob" now has two keys.  One can sudo su into root, one can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible using `pam_ssh_agent_auth` package if your distribution provides. It can allow you to execute sudo based on pam module, which checks possession of ssh key in ssh-agent.

## Short story long

### Setup

1. Install `pam_ssh_agent_auth` package from package manager
2. Modify `/etc/sudoers`, preferably using `visudo` and add line

   ```
   Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and add (as a second line after `#%PAM-1.0`)

   ```
   auth     sufficient   pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/security/authorized_keys
   ```

   and comment out line

   ```
   #auth       include      system-auth
   ```

   to disallow normal system authentication for sudo command
4. Create the "privileged" key-pair that should have access to the `sudo` command and the store public part as `/etc/security/authorized_keys` on server.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa > /etc/security/authorized_keys
   ```

### Usage

1. On client open ssh-agent and add above mentioned key:

   eval $(ssh-agent)
      ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2. Connect to server with agent forwarding

   ssh -K server
3. Run sudo as you wish

This works fine on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS systems, from what I tested so far.